# Approaches to work around differing signal lengths when using Kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filters, filtering, smoothing

I have a set of vector valued signals $\boldsymbol{y}_{1:T}$ where each $\boldsymbol{y}_k \in \mathbb{R}^{v_k}$. Each signal is potentially of different dimensionality. I'd like to apply filtering and smoothing in the usual Kalman case but I'm unsure how to get around the problem of each $y$ having a different length. My first guess was to use zero padding, to make all the $y$'s as large as the largest $y$. But I imagine this will cause problems for the Kalman filter. Does anyone know of works that deal with this issue?

Or is this an issue at all? Looking at the usual equations:

$$\boldsymbol{x}_k = \boldsymbol{I}_n\boldsymbol{x}_{k-1} + \boldsymbol{q}_{k-1} \tag 1$$

$$\boldsymbol{y}_k = \boldsymbol{H}_k\boldsymbol{x}_k + \boldsymbol{r}_k \tag 2$$

it seems if $y$ is changing then $H$ must also change accordingly in dimensions and so must $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this isn't (or at least may not be) an issue at all.  If you can model your system with a time-varying $\mathbf H_k$ and $\mathbf r_k$, then the correct Kalman filter will just drop out of the math.

Note that unless $\mathbf H_k$ and $\mathbf r_k$ are varying periodically, there's no sensible equivalent to a steady-state Kalman filter -- you're doomed to doing the entire calculation at each step.  But hey -- at least you can do *something*.